# How can I match all values nested in a collection to values in another collection (mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a messaging app and I need to be able to display the users with which a given user has conversation history. 
I have users and conversations. The models are below. (There is a messages collection where each document refers to a conversation)

```
//This is the conversation model.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ConversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  participants: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
});
const Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', ConversationSchema);

//This is the users model (there's more to it, but this is the relevant stuff)
module.exports = Conversation;
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Each has an _id that is generated.
I am sending an http request with a user ID.
In my controller, using mongoose, I am able to do the following:

```
Conversation.find({participants:req.params.user_id})
```

This returns an array of conversation objects, each of which contains a participants array(an array of user IDs).
What I then need to do is match all the participants to the "users" collection so I can get the user ID, first name and last name of each user.

In summary, I need to send an HTTP request with a user ID as a parameter and receive an array of users which have conversation history with the provided user.

What is the next step? How can I match the user IDs I get from the relevant conversations to the user IDs in the users collection?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
app.post('/:user_id', async(req, res) => {
 const partisipant = await Conversation.find({id:req.params.user_id});
 const userData = await User.find({id:req.params.user_id});
 if(!userData || userData != partisipant){
  throw ('no data match')
 }
 //...if found the data, do anything you want
})
```

Using async await to get collection data from database, and compare them.

Hope this clue can help you

Comment: I think in order for something like this to work, I would need the result to come back as the value (or array of values) and not as the object. As it stands, Conversation.find({participants:req.params.user_id}) returns an array of objects, where each object has an "_id" as well as "participants" key, and the participants value is an array of ID's. Is there a way to have the query return just the value, not the whole document?